# postgresql adjacency list query

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query, adjacency-list

In postgresql, I have the following table

```
c_relation_investor_main_pfk; c_relation_investor_sub_pfk
"inv_ho";"inv_ho_r"
"inv_ho";"inv_ho_sf"
"inv_priv";"inv_com"
"inv_priv";"inv_encor"
"inv_priv";"inv_ho"
"inv_prof";"inv_b4"
"inv_prof";"inv_com"
"inv_prof";"inv_encor"
"inv_prof";"inv_ho"
"inv_prof";"inv_pd"
"inv_prof";"inv_ut"
```

Given a child name, how can I list all the ascendants? And given a parent name, how can I list all of its descendants?

Comment: are they at least recursive?.. otherwise its just `select where colname = val` question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recursive-query+postgresql

Comment: @Vao Tsun yes, its recursive.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the solution so it may help someone facing similar problem.

```
WITH RECURSIVE source(main ,sub ) AS (
SELECT character varying 'inv_ho', character varying 'inv_ho_r'
UNION ALL
SELECT tb_relation_investor.c_relation_investor_main_pfk, tb_relation_investor.c_relation_investor_sub_pfk
FROM source JOIN tb_relation_investor ON (source.main=tb_relation_investor.c_relation_investor_sub_pfk)
 )
 SELECT * from source
```